# How to receive sms from a special phone number?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, sms, broadcastreceiver

I wrote a send and receive sms in android successfully.

I want my program to be able to receive sms from a special number("+9856874236"). But, if the SMS is from any other number, it should go to the phone's message inbox and not to my application.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public String str = "";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

            if (bundle != null)
            {

                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];      
                String msg_from="";
                for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) 
                {
                    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]); 
                      msg_from += msgs[n].getOriginatingAddress();
                }

                String receivedMessage = smsMessage[0].getMessageBody().toString().toUpperCase();


                if(msg_from .equals("+989124236870"))  
                {
                for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) 
                {

                    smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[n]); 
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[n].getOriginatingAddress();
                    str += " :";
                    //str += "sms az shomare makhsus";
                    str += msgs[n].getMessageBody().toString();

                    str += "\n";

               abortBroadcast();

               }


                Intent act = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                act.putExtra("message", str);
                context.startActivity(act);
            }


            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you have 4 similar questions open.
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108337/how-to-receive-sms-only-from-one-specific-number-other-smss-go-to-phones-inbox
2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097704/how-to-received-sms-from-special-number
3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107161/filtering-received-sms-in-android
4. This one.
Not cool. Please don't do it.

Comment: because I didnt get my answer for my problem!!!!!!!! I dont have any way!!! can you resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you appending the msg_from parameter in for loop?

```
msg_from += msgs[n].getOriginatingAddress();
```

Shouldn't it just be :

```
msg_from[n] = msgs[n].getOriginatingAddress();
```

Basically have an array for msg_from[n] and put each originating address into it for every message.
Then check this for every message by looping through the msg_from array?

You can move the check for origin inside the for loop as follows:

```
for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
           if(msg_from[n].equals("+9856874236")){  
                smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[n]); 
                str += "SMS from " + msg_from[n];
                str += " :";
                //str += "sms az shomare makhsus";
                str += msgs[n].getMessageBody().toString();

                str += "\n";

                 abortBroadcast();
               }else{
               //Do something else 
               }
           }
```

Comment: in if condition , it should not change? "if(msg_from .equals("+9856874236"))  "

Comment: Yes, it should. I have updated my answer to :
if(msg_from[n].equals("+9856874236"))

Comment: Okay, are you sure you're prepending the country code etc to the mobile number being checked for?
As in for India it would be +91 9XXXXXXXXX

Comment: for phone number, between country code and tel is space?ex, for Iran:+98 9xxxxxxxxx

Comment: nope.. It's without.
+989xxxxxxxxx is correct, but +9856874236 has only 10 digits.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Iran mentions that you should have at least 10 digits post +98 right?
[edit]

Comment: yes, i knew.it was just example.in program ,i wrote my phone number

Comment: So isn't the issue fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

use this sample and customize it:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SrvSmsListener extends Service {

    private BroadcastReceiver IncomingSMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        private static final String SMS_RECEIVED =
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {
            if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
                Bundle bundle = _intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                        messages[i] = SmsMessage
                                .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                        String strPhoneNo = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msg = message.getMessageBody();

                        if (msg.startsWith("my text"))
                        {
                            // this stops notifications to others
                            this.abortBroadcast();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = IncomingSMSReceiver;
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (IncomingSMSReceiver != null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(IncomingSMSReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I create new project and I put your code in class.java and for send class, I put my code , and for manifest, i put Previous codes , but it created force close when receive sms in phone!!!

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too.now i use this code and it works properly:

```
        `enter code here`  
         if ( extras != null ) {
        // get array data from SMS
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" ); // "pdus" is the key

        for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i ) {
            // get sms message
            SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
            // get content and number
            String body = sms.getMessageBody();
            String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
            // create display message

            if( address.contains("5558")){

            messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";
            messages += body + "\n";

       // notify new arriving message
            Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

        this.abortBroadcast();

    }
    }
```

and also don't forget use this code to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

 .....
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:exported="true" >
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />

</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

this program receive only from port="5558"(in emulators) and store other msg in your inbox.

is it(09124236870) your own phone number?!!!